# Машина состояний на PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть необходимость сделать что-то вроде машины состояний, чтобы командой можно переключаться между функциями.

Ниже набросал вариант того, как это реализовал я, на примере чат-бота. Но слышал я, за глобальные переменные тут больно бьют, да и в любом случае, функции будут витиеватые. 
Так что можно действительно не уследить. Ну и наверняка есть вариант поизящней.

**P.S.** Это я так думаю, что это машина состояний, насколько я это понял, но если не то - поправьте.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

keySwitcher_49 = 0


class MyWin(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 250)
        self.queen_browser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.queen_browser.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 190)
        self.queen_browser.setText('Hi')
        self.browser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.browser.setGeometry(0, 200, 400, 40)

    def start(self):
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text == 'hi':
            self.queen_browser.setText('Hello')
            self.hi_foo()
        if text == 'ask':
            self.queen_browser.setText('Yes?')
            self.ask_foo()

    def hi_foo(self):
        global keySwitcher_49
        keySwitcher_49 = 1
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text == 'how are you':
            self.queen_browser.setText('cool, and you?')
        if text == 'go back':
            self.queen_browser.setText(r'Alright, what\'s now?')
            keySwitcher_49 = 0

    def ask_foo(self):
        global keySwitcher_49
        keySwitcher_49 = 2
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text:
            self.queen_browser.setText(text + '? ' + random.choice(['Yes', 'No', 'May be']))
        if text == 'go back':
            self.queen_browser.setText(r'Alright, what\'s now?')
            keySwitcher_49 = 0

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return and keySwitcher_49 == 0:
            self.start()

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return and keySwitcher_49 == 1:
            self.hi_foo()

        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return and keySwitcher_49 == 2:
            self.ask_foo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Тут у меня глобальная переменная `keySwitcher_49` отвечает за состояние и после каждого нажатия энтер программа выкидывает в соответствующую функцию, а там уже я работаю с полученными с текстового поля данными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я немного упорядочил ваш код и никаких глобальных переменных. 
Попробуйте:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    keySwitcher_49 = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.queen_browser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.queen_browser.setText('Hi')
        self.browser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.browser.setToolTip(f'keySwitcher_49 = {self.keySwitcher_49}')
        self.placeholder_text()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.queen_browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.browser.setFocus() 

    def start(self):
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text == 'hi':
            self.queen_browser.setText('Hello')
            self.hi_foo()
        elif text == 'ask':
            self.queen_browser.setText('Yes?')
            self.ask_foo()

    def hi_foo(self):
        self.keySwitcher_49 = 1
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text == 'how are you':
            self.queen_browser.setText('cool, and you?')
        elif text == 'go back':
            self.queen_browser.setText(r'Alright, what\'s now?')
            self.keySwitcher_49 = 0
        self.browser.setToolTip(f'keySwitcher_49 = {self.keySwitcher_49}')

    def ask_foo(self):
        self.keySwitcher_49 = 2
        text = self.browser.text()
        self.browser.clear()
        if text:
            if text == 'go back':
                self.queen_browser.setText(r'Alright, what\'s now?')
                self.keySwitcher_49 = 0
            else:
                self.queen_browser.setText(text + '? ' + random.choice(['Yes', 'No', 'May be']))
            self.browser.setToolTip(f'keySwitcher_49 = {self.keySwitcher_49}')

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            if self.keySwitcher_49 == 0:
                self.start()
            elif self.keySwitcher_49 == 1:
                self.hi_foo()
            elif self.keySwitcher_49 == 2:
                self.ask_foo()
            self.placeholder_text()     
                
    def placeholder_text(self):
        if self.keySwitcher_49 == 0:
            self.browser.setPlaceholderText("Введите `hi` или `ask`")
        elif self.keySwitcher_49 == 1:
            self.browser.setPlaceholderText("Введите `how are you` или `go back`")
        elif self.keySwitcher_49 == 2:    
            self.browser.setPlaceholderText("Введите `go back` или `что-нибудь`")


qss = """
QLineEdit {
    background-color: rgb(227, 229, 235);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(227, 29, 35);
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    /* color: #f00;  */
}
QLineEdit:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgb(64, 71, 188);
}
QLineEdit:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(91, 201, 124);
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w = MyWin()
    w.resize(400, 250)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а, то есть можно же опустить переменную на уровень ниже, точно. Да, с глобальными переменными вопрос решен, однако есть ли варианты полаконичнее таких прыжков?